# python-telegram-bot 20.3 подскажите метод для загрузки файлов

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Какой модуль на Python позволяет загружать видео в Телеграм-боте для Telegram 20.x?
не могу корректно написать сам код загрузки видео

загружаемый pip: python-telegram-bot + upd

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import filters, ApplicationBuilder, ContextTypes, \
    Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler

app.add_handler(CommandHandler('video', show_video))
```

проблема тут:

```
async def show_video(update, context):
    video = open('video2.mp4', 'rb')
    await context.bot.send_video_note(context.chat.id, video,
                              reply_to_message_id=context.message_id)
```

как правильно указать метод, чтобы бот его загрузил в чат?
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_video_note'

Comment: Попробуйте так: `await update.message.reply_video_note(video, reply_to_message_id=context.message_id, reply_markup=None)`

Comment: спасибо, вот так сработало: async def show_video(update, context):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                   text="смотри видео")
    video = open('video2.mp4', 'rb')
    await update.message.reply_video_note(video, reply_markup=None)